# Setting the contents of a textBox to upper-case on CurrentItemChanged

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, textbox

I would like the text in my textBox to be set to upper-case whenever currentItemChanged is triggered. In other words, whenever the text in the box changes I'd like to make the contents upper-case. Here is my code:

```
private void rootBindingSource_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    toUserTextBox.Text.ToUpper();
    readWriteAuthorization1.ResetControlAuthorization();
}
```

The event triggers for sure, I've tested with a messageBox. So I know I've done something wrong here... the question is what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strings are immutable. ToUpper() returns a new string. Try this:

```
private void rootBindingSource_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    toUserTextBox.Text = toUserTextBox.Text.ToUpper();
    readWriteAuthorization1.ResetControlAuthorization();
}
```

Comment: Bingo. You can't just call a function on a string without reassigning it.

Comment: Lol... I'll blame it on fatigue :P

Answer (score 24):

If all you need to do is force the input to upper case, try the [CharacterCasing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.charactercasing.aspx) property of the textbox.

```
toUserTextBox.CharacterCasing = CharacterCasing.Upper;
```

Comment: Unless you specifically need to handle something else in that event, you can just set that through the properties menu for that textbox. as well.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine that your question is Why your code is not working.

You are not assigning the "Uppered" text to the textbox again.

Should be:

```
private void rootBindingSource_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    toUserTextBox.Text = toUserTextBox.Text.ToUpper();
    readWriteAuthorization1.ResetControlAuthorization();
}
```